# C Beginner: Can't use delay() in a simple C program

Tags: c, macos, compilation, delay

## test1.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  printf("test\n");
  delay(1000);
  printf("test2\n");
}
```

When I try to compile...

```
gcc test1.c -o test1
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_delay", referenced from:
      _main in ccUnw3tY.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Certainly there is a lesson here in knowing your libraries and what linking is etc... What am I missing? I am trying to do this on OSX.

Comment: Pretty much everyone's answer below helps me. Thanks guys. usleep works great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no delay function in C, you have to use `sleep` or `usleep` depending on what OS you're on.

Comment: Now - hold on a minute. It's possible that the OP is reading a book for another system then OSX, in which case there may well be a function named `delay`. There just isn't one in POSIX (which is what OSX is largely based on).

Answer (score 1):

What make you think there is a delay function. I dont see one in the osx docs. There is a sleep function

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/sleep.3.html

Comment: So that makes sense. The problem is I want to work in milliseconds and sleep(0.01) takes a full 1 second to run, the same as sleep(1).

Comment: @Beaon, that's what `usleep` is for.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative of delay in C for unix os is the sleep function : 
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/sleep.3.html
do something like :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
  printf("test\n");
  usleep(1000);
  printf("test2\n");
}
```

If you value is for 1000 microsecondes.

Comment: Just note that `usleep` takes *microseconds*, not milliseconds.

Comment: I think you mean microseconds.

Comment: Edited, sorry for my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The delay function works in Borland C compiler. You have to use the `dos.h` header file in order to use delay. Some other compilers like `MinGW` may not support this.