# sleep() function not working?

Tags: c, linux, windows, sleep

I'm using GNU GCC compiler in Code::Blocks on Windows. Why doesn't sleep(seconds) work here? I've tried it using  library and it works fine. Thanks.

Edit: By "doesn't work" I mean, doesn't compile. Sorry.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char * c = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*50);
    if(--argc>0){
        printf("POTATO: \n");
        while(argc>=1){
            printf("- %s\n", argv[argc]);
            sleep(10);
            argc--;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("A\n");
    scanf("%s", c);
    printf("What you wrote: %s\n", c);
    scanf("%s", c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not work"

Comment: delay() from time.h, in linux sleep doesn't works

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: What is `delay()` please?

Comment: @alk no I seach there is no delay but I could have find [C Beginner: Can't use `delay( )` in a simple C program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148545/c-beginner-cant-use-delay-in-a-simple-c-program)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: There was one, decades ago in TC, I think.

Comment: @alk Yes I have used in school time.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: Please don't get me wrong, I wasn't referring to your current english!

Comment: @alk no I just mean to say C language is better than my communication..:) :)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming "*doesn't work* means "*doesn't compile*":

[`sleep()` is IX'ish](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sleep.html). The appropriate [win32 call would be `Sleep()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The difference is that the latter takes ms, but s, as `sleep()` does.

---

To have portable code writing your own wrapper like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14818830/694576 might help.

Comment: It doesn't compile I think: "undefined reference to 'sleep'"
I know about that ms and s difference, my question is: If I'm using the same compiler and library as in linux why doesn't it work...

Comment: @SadSeven: The win32's `Sleep()` starts with a capital `S`.

Comment: @SadSeven It does not work because there is no sleep() function in windows. There is a Sleep() function (with a capital S), but it takes miliseconds instead of seconds.

Comment: @SadSeven The compiler doesn't matter. It is the library that matters. And unless you get a library with the same interface as you have under linux, it just won't work.

Comment: I know that guys, that's not the point lol. The one with <windows.h> is working fine. I don't understand why doesn't the <unistd.h> work (compile).

Comment: You're using the wrong compiler suite, or the wrong functionality (can look at it from either side). The header `unistd.h` contains, as the name would suggest, "unix standard" functions, i.e. POSIX functions. Windows is not POSIX compliant, and MinGW _explicitly does not attempt to_ provide a complete POSIX compatibility layer. If this is what you want, use Cygwin.

Comment: @Damon: Your comment was addressed to *SadSeven*, wasn't it?

Comment: @alk: Yes, I did not @ the OP since I thought it was obvious, and I was under the impression that question OP _always_ gets mailboxed, is that not true?

Comment: @Damon: I think only the answerer is notified. But you are right, the questioner also might be. Anybody correct me if I'm wrong, I cannot remember, as posing to few questions ... :-} (it "*was obvious* to me btw, yes)

Comment: @SadSeven There are many portability issues, this is one of them. See here for a solution https://www.mail-archive.com/wsjt-devel@lists.berlios.de/msg01067.html . For a more comprehensive solution there is Apache Portable Runtime (for example) which provides wrappers for many functions which have potential portability problems such as sleep, timezones, directory listings, character encodings etc

Answer (score 0):

because command line argument argc is 1. so if condition is not working,
use print statement before if() condition.